# Add spfx webpart to a page in subsite sp online

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts, deployment, sub-site

I have created a spfx webpart and deployed it in site collection app catalog. But when I try to add it in modern page in subsite, webpart is not displayed for adding it to page. What is that I m missing here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you also have to add the app to the subweb?

Here, "trello-import-client-side-solution" is a package that is deployed to the Site Collection App Catalog, but since it does not have `skipFeatureDeployment`set in `package-solution.json`, it will have to be added manually.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for timely response.